Use registry_package of another docker repo
I would like to use event like this
on:
  registry_package:
    types: [published, updated]
    registry: github_docker_repo

where github_docker_repo is docker repository that can be updated or pushed from another github git repository.
So, now the event doesn't work. Can I do this cross-repository action without usage of webhooks, like repository_dispatch for example?
